# How to get only contacts with birthdays in upcoming ascending order in android?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying to fetch only those contacts for which birthday or anniversary information is available. However, I only found way to get contacts with phone number, but my app needs only contacts with birthday/anniversary information available and sorted in their upcoming birthdays order.

I am showing the results in `ListView`.

I need proper query to get around this problem, I tried googling and stackoverflow but found no solution.

Here is the code I'm using to get the information about contacts:

```
    Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
     String SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY + " ASC ";

            // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
            Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1",
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");

if (contactsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

                    Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

                    String[] projection1 ={
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA2,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA1,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA15
                    };

                    // Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
                    // home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact

                    String selection =
                            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId;

Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            dataUri,
                            projection1,   //projection
                            selection,   //selection
                            null,
                            null); 
        ////some code here
        } while (dataCursor.moveToNext());

   ////some more code

   // Adding id, display name, path to photo and other details to cursor
                    mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{Long.toString(contactId), displayName, photoPath, details});
                }
            } while (contactsCursor.moveToNext());
        }


        return mMatrixCursor;

    }
```

I am getting all the required information correctly and having no problem with that, however I'm struggling in finding proper query to show only contacts with birthdays and sorting them in proper order as birthdays are not always stored in proper format. Thanks in advance !

Comment: while you are looping cant you add to array list, then just call Collections sort ?

Comment: Adding to array list and then calling collections sort would sort the contacts and also give me required contacts, but for that matter query will fetch all contacts with phone numbers as it's doing now. It will degrade performance as I still have to fetch all contacts which I won't be showing. Anyways thanks for that solution.